# Share Ext4 Partition Over Network

Tags: samba, ext4, shared-folders

I have an Ext4 partition (not auto-mounted) that I would like to share (entirely) in my home that contains Mac OSX, Windows and Linux machines (currently the most important is sharing with the Mac). How may I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Essentially, you will want to create a Samba share for the Ext4 mount point.  Open-up  your /etc/samba/smb.conf (in your favorite editor) and alter a few things:

1 - **workgroup** - you'll want to set that to the name of your network workgroup, if you have one.

2 - **security = user** - even if this line is commented-out, user-level security is the default for Samba.

3 - Define your Samba share at the bottom of the file.  You should see a (commented-out) example at the bottom.  You'll need the mount point of your ext4 partition (that you want to share).  If you're not sure of what that is, do a "df -k" from terminal, and you should see it (put it in the "path" setting instead of "/some/directory").

```
[ShareName]
path = /some/directory
browsable = yes
valid users = myUser, user2, user3
```

4 - Next, you'll need to alter the permissions on the path (mount point) to ensure that the desired users can accomplish what they need to.

5 - Restart Samba

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

6 - Connect to your Samba share from your Mac.  I found instructions on that [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568).  Essentially, it says:

> When you go to the Connect to Server dialog, you may browse the names
>   of computers that are on your local subnet.
>
> You can connect to a
>   server via its IP address or DNS name. If it is required or more
>   convenient in your environment, you may also use other valid URL
>   formats, such as:
>
> ```
> smb://ServerName/ShareName
> ```

For me, I connect to my Samba shares by IP:

```
smb://192.168.0.117/ShareName
```

For troubleshooting, check the doc that I referenced: 
[Mac OS X: How to connect to Windows File Sharing (SMB)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I already have samba and I share some of the directories with my Mac, so can I just edit the smb.conf file now and restart samba to get it working?

Comment: If the ext4 partition is mounted and you specify its mount point as the path, then (in theory) "yes" it should work.

Comment: Editing the file worked, only a small addition, to enable sharing with guests, I had to add `guest ok = yes` Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the venerable but complicated method of manually editing configuration files, unless you need to extensively customize who can access the share, you can simply:

1. Navigate in Nautilus (the file browser) to the [mount point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_point) of the drive you want to share (e.g., `/media/MyDrive`).
2. Go up to the parent directory (in this example, `/media`).
3. Right-click on the drive name (`MyDrive`), and click **Sharing Options**.

[image: Folder Sharing in Nautilus - If you want people to be able to access it without logging in, check the box labeled: "Guest access (for people without a user account)"]

As you can see, enabling guest access is as simple as checking the box for it.

> Nautilus might tell you that you have to install some packages to
>   share a folder. This will happen if Samba and its dependencies are not
>   already installed. You can say yes to this. After installation, you
>   may have to log out and back in (rebooting also works but is not
>   necessary). Then go back to Sharing Options. Now that the necessary
>   packages are installed, you can share the folder.

This method works for sharing statically mounted volumes (like yours), dynamically mounted volumes, or any folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was pretty much time ago so I can't recall exactly why, but this was my first approach and it failed for some reason. I had no such problem with normal folders, only with mounted folders...

Comment: If you try to select a drive in the device list and share it, this won't work. You have to actually navigate to the mount point's parent folder (which is usually `/media`) to do this. Perhaps that was the problem you were having.

Comment: That's explains it :) will try when I get home. thanks.

Comment: Many times on many different Ubuntu versions and machines I've tried this approach. I know it should work, but it never has. I'll try all the advice on this page and if it doesn't work, ask a very specific question.