# share folders between two Ubuntu 12.04 machines

Tags: nautilus, file-sharing

I have two machines (1 laptop, 1 desktop) on same network connected to a router both have `Ubuntu 12.04`.
I need to share my e.g. "movies drive" from Desktop computer so that i can watch those on laptop just by accessing it through  `Nautilus`.

Currently in my nautilus it only shows `Windows Networks` under `Browse Networks` and fails to show my desktop over there.

Thanks

Comment: Do the machines have sharing enabled?

Comment: This question has answers for solving this via Samba and folder sharing - http://askubuntu.com/questions/119668/share-ext4-partition-over-network/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, to share folder between `Ubuntu` machines: choose folder -> right click -> folder sharing(or in file Properties).

If your computer isn't shown in Browse Network, maybe your network isn't configured right way. But anyway you can try the next:
open nautilius, press Ctrl+L, and put `smb://ip.address`(change ip.address with ip of PC you wanna connect to, like `smb://192.168.1.1`

Comment: Thanks this worked...
Maybe others will work too but it was simplest. 
Thank You.

Comment: can i make a softlink to this folder which will save typing and just opening that folder will take me here??

Comment: No. The link won't work until you mount the resource. If you need it always be mounted than you can mount it when Ubuntu starts.

Comment: Is this safe on a non-private network?

Comment: I would not recommend to use it on public networks, smb protocols is used for private(home) networks. On public networks I recommend to use `SFTP`(SSH FTP)

Answer (score 2):

You can access files on a remote computer using [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell):

1. Install `openssh-server` on a computer you want to connect to.
2. Choose `File -> Connect to Server` in Nautilus running on a machine you want to connect from and select `SSH`.
3. Enter the remote machine name (you may need to use the `.local` suffix), user name (on remote machine), password and (optionally) folder name and click `Connect`.

The remote folder will appear in the sidebar and will be accessible as your local folders.

You can even setup a passwordless connection. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great link for sharing folder in ubuntu. (Configuration)
Try to check it out. https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/networking-shares.html

On the section of Sharing folders via Nautilus you will make it work.

Tell us if it work

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.