# Give full permission to a folder in an Ethernet

Tags: networking, gnome, gnome-terminal

I have two ubuntu machines (`machineA` and `machineB`)connected through a wired Ethernet cable. I'm asking how I can give full permission and access of `machineA` to a certain folder `Folder1` in the `machineB` over the network using terminal?

Comment: You mean you want a folder of machineA to appear and be writable on machineB?

Comment: Please mentions which protocols are you using for access?And accordingly change the firewalls settings if enabled. Directory permissions could be changed with chmod 777 dir_path for every user and group.Check dir. properties for sharing options. And plz describe what do you mean by full permissions.

Comment: @LnxSlck, Yes. What is happening is that there is a folder in machineB that I want userA in machineA have full access so that it can write and access it

Comment: @kashminder firewall is disabled. I always use chmod 777 to give access on the same machine, but I never did something like that over a network between two machines

Comment: If so, you have complete permissions to read write and execute over the network too.

Comment: @kashminder what do you mean by "if so"? I meant that if I'm working on machineA I use chmod 777 to give access to any folder on it between different users on it. But my current situation is different than that. Now I have another machine connected to this machine, and I want to give users of this new machine full access to a certain folder on the old machine. I don't know how to do this?

Comment: Another one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176248/share-folders-between-two-ubuntu-12-04-machines

Comment: are u using samba,nfc or ssh to share files on network. Settings are done on their configuration files regardless of ssh.

Comment: http://imgur.com/QZNBiWL     Follow this link and read the file. The read only and create mode.

Comment: @kashminder I'm using ssh

Comment: In ssh you are logged in as a system user. Means you are logged in as a user of m/c A. So permissions are the same of User a. you can copy files and directory by using scp and open it on the go. Just look at the username,when you are logged in as the ssh user. or read an ssh mannual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I see two possibilities: Samba or NFS.  Both are client/server software which means you need to install the client part on your machineA and the server part on your machineB.  From that point on, you can get access the files on the server via any software (including terminal) on the client.

On the differences, samba is based on the windows world.  Therefore, files made available in samba are readily available also to Windows-based PC.

NFS stands for Network File System and allows you to mount on PC A (the client) directories that reside on PC B (the server).  Once setup, it is completely transparent to the user.  A standard windows PC would not see them, however.
A more complete discussion on the differences can be found here: [Which to use NFS or Samba?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7117/which-to-use-nfs-or-samba)

For a fairly complete discusion on how to install NFS, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo