# Windows Workgroup issue

Tags: networking, windows-7, permissions, users, workgroup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share Ext4 Partition Over Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119668/share-ext4-partition-over-network)

How to configure my Ubuntu Workstation to be a member of Windows 7 Workgroup ? and How to manage permissions for windows users accessing my Ubuntu machine