# Samba configuration problem

Tags: samba

I want to access samba from windows 7 and if i copy any data from server to win7 machine it automatic replicate (take the backup) the data to another machine.

Please suggest me how can i do it.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

[**Install and Configure Samba Server as File Server on Ubuntu Server 12.04**](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/06/install-samba-server-ubuntu-server-1204-lts.html)

http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/06/install-samba-server-ubuntu-server-1204-lts.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar on my Windows 7 partition, using Samba (on my Ubuntu Server) and Ubuntu One as a quick and easy backup/replication solution.

First install Samba (if you don't already have it) on your Ubuntu machine.

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbfs
```

Next, you'll have to configure Samba and set up a share.  Here is an answer I posted that details how to do that: [Share Ext4 Partition Over Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119668/share-ext4-partition-over-network/119684#119684)

Once configured, you should be able to connect to your Samba share from Windows 7 by opening a file explorer window and typing the following into the address bar:

```
\\192.168.0.101\myShareName
```

Obviously, replace the `192.168.0.101` with the (internal) IP address of your Ubuntu machine.  Also replace `myShareName` with the name of the share you have configured in Samba.

Now that Samba is configured and reachable, download and install the [Ubuntu One Windows client](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/).  If you don't have an Ubuntu One account, you can create one during the installation process or by following this link: [Ubuntu One - Create Account](https://login.ubuntu.com/+new_account).  Once the client is installed and has connected to the Ubuntu One cloud, open it and you should see something similar to this:

[image]

Note that you can see the file explorer for my Samba share in the background.

By default, Ubuntu One will create a sync'd directory in the following location on your windows drive (represented here as "x:").  Unless your Windows installation is configured otherwise, it will probably be "c:".

```
x:\Users\%username%\Ubuntu One
```

Now, anything you copy down from your Ubuntu server (via your Samba share) to your Ubuntu One directory will be replicated to the Ubuntu One cloud.  If you wish, you can also configure the Ubuntu One client to sync additional directories.  This data will be replicated to all machines running an Ubuntu One client that are connected to your account.