# How to setup an Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 12.04, server, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share Ext4 Partition Over Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119668/share-ext4-partition-over-network)

I have no knowledge when it comes to servers and i really want to be a pro at stuff like that.

What i wanna do is setup a Ubuntu server like in schools you get a username and a password and then you can log into your account from any computer in the school and still have those files you have on your user.

Is there any easy way to setup a Ubuntu server like that? or could someone give me a step by step tutorial? I have a spare computer that i can use as a server

Answer (score 0):

I think you need samba

*Samba is an implementation of the Server Message Block (SMB)/Common Internet File System (CIFS) protocol for Unix systems, providing support for cross-platform file and printer sharing with Microsoft Windows, OS X, and other Unix systems.*

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba?action=show&redirect=SettingUpSamba