# Can connect ubuntu with windows workgroup

Tags: workgroup

I have a two systems in my home, one is windows 7 and other is ubuntu precise pangolin. Now i want to connect my two systems in one workgroup for sharing purpose. Is it possible to achieve this..?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use samba for your requirement  This has been already explained in this  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119668/share-ext4-partition-over-network)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The easy way is to  install sharing on ubuntu , right click on a folder and select share. The first time you do this it will want to intall packages and log out. when shared you can type the unc path ubuntuhostname or ip in wondow and get the shares. It should also show up on wondows network places thing.

The harder way is to install samba (sudo apt-get install samba) and configure /etc/samba/smb.conf to your liking. Then add shares.

Comment: click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) if you want to install and configure samba server.

Answer (score 1):

I use teamviewer for desktop pc's and vnc for server.

I never did this myself, but I use these two programs often for remote desktop. I believe they both have it somewhere in their options, but never bothered to configure a proper sync folder since I just copy/paste in teamviewer or use a ftp for vncviewer & vncserver