# Error when mounting a shared drive via Samba

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I have set up a windows workgroup in order to see my network drive.

The network shows it but I can't mount it via smb4K and access it.

And get the error message

```
The Share "//MYBOOKLIVE/Public could not be mounted
mount.cifs:permission denied:no match for /home/viktoria/smb4k/MYBOOKLIVE/Public in etc/fstab
```

I have installed samba
sudo apt-get install samba

I have opened the configuration 
sudo gedit/etc/samba/smb.conf
 and changed the file according to [Share Ext4 Partition Over Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119668/share-ext4-partition-over-network) using of course my configuration. My computer can trace find the other computer on the network, can find the printers and the network drive but I cannot mount it or access the files. I am sorry for my silly questions but I am a first time Ubuntu user and i understand very little about it.

I have to mention that there are two workgroups that I am connecting to. The one has two windows PCs and the other has only the network drive. I don't why this is happening. The other thing is that sometimes I see the workgroup with the network drive in the smb4K and sometimes i don't. I am pretty sure that I have to do something more but I don't know what.

What do I have to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you put in your question the command(s) / manipulation you've done trying to mount the network drive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you have installed samba

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

In the Global section of the file /etc/samba/smb.conf I have this :-

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = PCNAME
name resolve order = bcast host
```

Change WORKGROUP and PCNAME accordingly.
Set the name resolve order as shown in order to browse windows shares using Nautilus.

Comment: I don't have Nautilus and I don't know how to install it.

Comment: What do you use as your file manager, is it not nautilus ? sudo apt-get install nautilus

Comment: Thank you. I can see now the files in my network drive. The only problem is that when I try to open an office file like excel saves by a windows PC it appears an import/export error and does not open it. I have libre office 3 Any idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, if you google you will see many people with same problem opening a file from a network share with libre office 3. I use my windows machine for office, which is a shame because I like libre office !